# Finding the numbers $n$ such that $2n+5$ is composite.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than zero. I write

$$a_n =
\begin{cases}
1 , &\text{ if } n=0 \\
1 , &\text{ if } n=1 \\
n(n-1), & \text{ if $2n-1$ is prime} \\
3-n, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The sequence goes like this $$1,1,2,6,12,-2,30,42,-5,72,90,-8,132,-10,-11,\ldots$$ I would like to prove the following two claims.

> ***claim 1*** : If $a_n>0$ and
>   ${a_n \above 1.5 pt 3} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ then $\sqrt{4a_n+1}$ is prime.

The table below illustrates what I am seeing:

\begin{array}{| l | l | l | l }
\hline
n & a_n  & {a_n \above 1.5 pt 3} & \sqrt{4a_n+1}\\ \hline
0 & 1 &  .333333.. & 2.2360679.. \\ 
1 & 1 &  .333333.. & 3 \\ 
2 & 2 &  .666666..  & 3   \\ 
3 & 6 &  2   & 5   \\ 
4 & 12 &  4   & 7   \\ 
6 & 30 & 10   & 11    \\ 
7 & 42 & 14  & 13     \\ 
9 & 72 & 24  & 17 &   \\ 
10 & 90 & 30   & 19  \\ 
12 & 132 & 44   & 23  \\ 
15 & 210 & 70   & 29  \\ 
16 & 240 & 80  & 31  \\ 
19 & 342 & 114   & 37 \\ 
21 & 420 & 140   & 41 \\ 
22 & 462 & 154   & 43 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{array}

> ***claim 2***: If $a_n<0$ then $2a_n+5$ is composite

Comment: How can $\frac{a_n}{3}$ not be rational.  $a_n$ is an integer

Comment: I am trying to say that $a_n/3$ is not a fraction?

Comment: If $a_n$ is an integer, then $a_n/3$ is 'not a fraction' if and only if $a_n$ is a multiple of $3$, ie, iff $a_n \in 3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think what you mean is:
$${a_n \above 1.5 pt 3} \notin \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: If $a_0 = a_1 = 1$, why are the respective entries in the fourth column for $\sqrt{4a_n + 1}$ different?

Comment: The second claim is bound to be false, since it would mean that one of $2n-1$ or $2n+5$ is prime for all $n>3$, which would mean that for all odd number $x$, either $x$ or $x+6$ is a prime.

Comment: It seems to be true for the first several hundred terms, though ?

Comment: for claim $1$, all of the $a_n$ in your table are divisible by $3$  Indeed, $2n-1$ n odd prime implies $a_n=n(n-1)$ is divisible by $3$....so what does your condition mean?

Comment: @lulu The table is to support the claim. If $n=5$ then $a_n=-2$ and $-2$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: But Claim $1$ seems tautological....as $\sqrt {4a_n+1}=2n-1$ which you already assumed was prime.

Comment: @lulu Are you suggesting I am going in a circle with respect to claim 1. So it is true by "defeinition" ?

Comment: If $a_n>0$ and $n>3$ then that means $2n-1$ is prime (since $a_n>0$) and and $\sqrt{4a_n+1}=\sqrt{4n^2-4n+1}=2n-1$, which you already know is prime - the same prime.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez  Yes.  Claim $1$ has no content at all.

Comment: OK that settles claim 1.

Comment: And Claim $2$ is false (as the counterexample $n=13$ shows).

Comment: Ok, post edit $n=13$ is no longer a counterexample, but $n=17$ is:  we have $2\times 17-1=33$ and, as $33$ is composite, $a_{17}=3-n=-14$, yes?  But then $2\times a_{17}+5=-23$ which is surely not composite.

Comment: Right so this question is circuitous? It is just going in circles? The claims are true Implicitly ?

Comment: @quasi, that should be *is* a member of, not *is not* a member of.  If the intended predicate is "is not a fraction."

Comment: @Wildcard -- yes, thanks, but I can't edit my comment to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

$n=13$ is a counter example for claim 2.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.   Seems like a perfectly good counterexample to me (+1).

Comment: Please see the update to the the second claim due to a typo. Sorry  about that.

Comment: While it may be difficult to keep pace with the "update... due to a typo", a fuller statement of the conclusion and reasoning behind it would be a significant improvement as Answer, benefiting future Readers even if the Question changes further.

Comment: Given that if $a_n<0$ then $a_n=3-n$ and $2a_n+5=11-2n$, It is hard to see why this is composite. However, $5-2a_n=2n-1$ is known to be composite, which means $5+2|a_n|$ is composite.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Good catch.  I expect this is what the OP intended.  Tautological, again.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore $n = 0, 1$ since they're kind of irrelevant.  Then $a_n \leq 0$ for all $n$ unless $2n - 1$ is prime, by the definition.  In that case $a_n = n(n - 1)$. So,

$$4a_n + 1 = 4(n^2 - n) + 1 = (2n-1)^2$$

So, then $\sqrt{4a_n + 1} = 2n - 1$, which is prime.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify I have that both claims are trivially true and are explicit in the definition of $a_n$.

For claim 1 we have from @callus:

> ***proof of claim 1***: $a_n \leq 0$ for all $n$ unless $2n - 1$ is prime, by the definition.  In that case $a_n = n(n - 1)$. So, $4a_n +
> > 1 = 4(n^2 - n) + 1 = (2n-1)^2$. So  $\sqrt{4a_n + 1} = 2n - 1$,
>   which is prime.

For claim 2 we have from @Thomas Andrews

> ***proof of claim 2***: Given that if $a_n<0$ then $a_n=3−n$ and $2a_n+5=11−2n$, It is hard to see why this is composite. However,
>   $5−2a_n=2n−1$ is known to be composite, which means $5+2|a_n|$ is
>   composite.

Answer (score -1):

Claim 1 is vaccuously true, since given any $n$, $a_{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

It also looks like n=14 is a counterexample to claim 2.

Proof: 
$3-14=-11$ and $2(-11)+5=-17$ has positive divisors $1$ and $17$ only.